# Calculating Weighted Average for Multiple groups on 1 Page

Tags: excel

I am calculating hypothetical weighted average income by zip code. There are ~1,000 different zip codes, and I'd like to easily drag the equation for all of them. Each Zip code consists of 6 different incomes and then the number of people at that level within the zip code.

Here is a screen grab of one group.

[image]

There are approximately 1,000 of these groups directly below this one. The formula I have used in (C,3) is =(B3/$B$2)*A3.  When I use that formula, I can drag it from C3 to C8 and get the correct numbers.

However, if I want to continue moving it down to the next group, I need the value for the total number of people to change with it. If I don't use '$' it will then just divide by the cell directly above it.

How can I structure my formula so that I can drag it down without having to manually enter it each time.

Thanks for your help, and if I am unclear on any details, please let me know.

Comment: where is your zip code column?

Comment: if you can tweak your data to have the zip code in one column, you could run something like `=sumproduct((A:A<>"")*(ZipColumn=Zip)*(B:B)*(A:A))/sumifs(B:B,A:A,"<>",ZipColumn,Zip)`

Comment: Column E. Each row has the associated Zip code in Column E. In the sample above. E2-E8 all have the same zip code value.

Comment: Yes, zip code would be helpful. Get rid of the "total" row (the 240). Then, if your zip codes were in column E, the formula could look like this: `=($B2/SUMIFS($B:$B,$E:$E,"="&$E2))*$A2`. Tested, and this works, even if you sort the data by something other than the default.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked and I am all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in column C, you can use

```
=$A2*$B2/SUMIFS($B:$B,$E:$E,$E2)
```

You can also do away with column C completely and get your average by zip code with the following formula

```
=sumproduct(($E:$E=$e8)*($B:$B)*($A:$A))/SUMIFS($B:$B,$E:$E,$E2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help also, I've got this all set now.